# How to interpret and calculate scattering in a dark-field microscopy?

Tags: optics, scattering, microscopy

[image: dark-field microscopy]

*Dark-field microscopy setup from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-field_microscopy#Conventional_dark-field_imaging), which says the images in dark-field microscopy are scattering lights from the sample.*

My questions:

- When the sample is illuminated, is it correct to classify lights collected images as:

  - Absorb; (bright field image)
  - Diffract; (phase contrast image)
  - Scatter; (dark field image)
- Can I say the dark-field microscopy collects all the lights that are not (i) absorbed (ii) diffracted, so the collected image is pure scattering light?
- Are there any formulas to quantitatively calculate the scattering from the sample? For example, I can use wave optics and the scalar diffraction theory to calculate absorption and diffraction. So what is the corresponding theory in scattering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I can now answer my own question.

The dark-field microscopy, indeed, captures the scattering lights from the sample.

In the following consider one single sample point under one single illumination ray. That said, there is one single ray hits onto that one sample point.

- When there is no scattering, that particular input ray will: (i) gets attenuated, which is the sample absorption due to reduced irradiance power; and (ii) deflects, which is the diffraction (in Fresnel sense). So, one ray in, one ray out.
- When there is scattering, one ray in, multiple rays out. Of that multiple rays, one principle ray is dominant, which is the previous deflection ray. All the other rays, which heavily deflect, are scattering rays.

Since for most bio-samples the refraction is small. Thus, the configuration setup figure rejects all the absorption and diffraction, but preserves rays that deflect much away from its original input direction. And hence, the sensor captures part of the scattering rays.

Now go back to the questions.

- Yes.
- Yes. But only part of the scattering light is captured.
- Generally it is hard to compute the scattering using formulas. In practice people do experimental setups to capture the transport matrix (which is the collection of all the rays), e.g. in imaging through scattering media research.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> When the sample is illuminated, is it correct to classify lights collected images as:
>     Absorb; (bright field image)
>     Diffract; (phase contrast image)
>     Scatter; (dark field image)
> ```

No, phase contrast is dark field + some phase change not especially diffraction , and dark field relies on diffraction (and refraction) to perform scattering.

> Can I say the dark-field microscopy collects all the lights that are
>   not (i) absorbed (ii) diffracted, so the collected image is pure
>   scattering light?

-no microscope can collect light absorbed by the sample, so (i) is moot

-(ii)just see the drawing you posted in your question, diffracted light is clearly captured by the darkfield image

-again scattering is caused in part by diffraction

> ```
> Are there any formulas to quantitatively calculate the scattering from the sample? For example, I can use wave optics and the scalar
> ```
>
> diffraction theory to calculate absorption and diffraction. So what is
>   the corresponding theory in scattering?

you may get some formulas working if your sample is a pattern (like a grating, a crystal etc...)
Otherwise a [point spread function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) is usually used